# Circular permutation of n married couples sitting alternatively

Tags: probability, permutations, self-learning

This is the problem statement (First Course in Prob., Sheldon Ross, 8th Ed., Q 4.67):

> A total of $2n$ people, consisting of $n$ married couples, subject to the constraint that the men
> and women alternate, are randomly seated (all possible orderings being equally likely) at a round table. Let $C_i$ denote the event that the members of couple i are seated next to each other, $i = 1, ... , n$. 
> (a) Find $P(C_i)$.
> (b) For $j \neq i$, find $P(C_j | C_i)$.
> (c) Approximate the probability, for $n$ large, that there are no married couples who are seated next to each other.

I am assuming couples are man-woman here.

For part $(a)$, I let either of the two gender sit first *(whom to choose first does not matter in circular arrangement)* in $(n-1)!$ and the remaining people in $n$ places in $n!$ ways. Thus total ways is $n!(n-1)!$. Now, let women sit first in $(n-1)!$, followed by husband of $C_i$ in $2$ ways, followed by $(n-1)$ men-spaces in $(n-1)!$ ways. Thus, $P(C_i) = \frac{2 \cdot ((n-1)!)^2}{(n-1)! \cdot n!} = \frac{2}{n}$

For $(b)$, [I have seen solution for Problem 4.67](https://adembo.su.domains/math-151/sol4.pdf) as well as in the solution manual:

> Conditioning on whether the man of couple j sits next to the woman of couple i gives the
> result: $\frac{1}{n-1} \cdot \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{n-2}{n-1} \cdot \frac{2}{n-1} = \frac{2n-3}{(n-1)^2}  $

I do not understand either of the 2 solutions for part $(b)$ . Regarding how they are conditioning on the couple $C_i$ and $C_j$ sitting together, or how is that permutation working. This part $(b)$ is what I need help for.

Kindly explain in the absolute basic terms.
Thanks you! {{{(＞﹏＜)}}}

Answer (score 3):

**More Intuitive Part A**

Two women sits next to husband $i$: one on the left and one on the right. Out of $n$ women, what's the probability that the one sitting on his left is his wife? $\frac{1}{n}$ right? How about on his right? Also $\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore the probability for part $A$ is

$$
\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{2}{n}
$$

**Part B**

The couple $i$ sits together. Husband $j$ cannot sit next to husband $i$, so he either $(1)$ sits next to wife $i$ or $(2)$ he sits away from the couple $i$.

*Scenario $(1)$*

Husband $i$ sits on one side of wife $i$. From the remaining $n-1$ men, what's the probability that the one sitting on the other side of wife $i$ is husband $j$? $\frac{1}{n-1}$ right?

Now, wife $i$ sits on one side of husband $j$. From the remaining $n-1$ women, what's the probability that the one sitting on the other side of husband $j$ is his own wife? $\frac{1}{n-1}$ right?

This is the origin of the first product in the answer: $\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}$

*Scenario $(2)$*

Husband $i$ sits on one side of wife $i$. From the remaining $n-1$ men, what's the probability that the one sitting on the other side of wife $i$ is NOT husband $j$? $\frac{n-2}{n-1}$ right?

Now husband $j$ sits away from the couple $i$. On the left and right of him sit one woman each. From the $n-1$ remaining women (excluding wife $i$), what's the probability that the one sitting on his left is his wife? $\frac{1}{n-1}$ right? How about on his right? Also $\frac{1}{n-1}$.

This is the origin of the second product in the answer: $\frac{n-2}{n-1}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I noticed in both the cases, that you didn't point out that they are sitting in circular way. According to that, would the answer not remain the same had it been linear, which is actually not? I am slightly confused, because although I noticed you did the conditioning on whether they are sitting together or not, you did not use the formula. Can you please elaborate further on that?

Comment: @Roy they sit in circular way, so there is always someone sitting on one’s left and right side. If they sit in a linear way, we need to consider cases in which they sit at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks! One question: How did you figure out that those 2 couples sitting together (or not) are the only cases to be considered? I am not able to figure how to reach the same solution

Comment: @Roy because the question only asks about those two couples :) . It's a common pattern in combinatorics problem: seemingly a lot of variables but in the end only a small subset of variables matter to the problem

Comment: Okay. If I want to approach part (B) as using conditional probability, can you give me an approach to proceed? As in using $P(C_j|C_i)$ formula?